# Proving that $x^a-y^a<x-y$ for $0<y<x<1$ and $a \in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I have to prove this simple inequality, to complete another proof. But I don't know where to start anymore.

The inequality as in the title is: $x^a-y^a<x-y$ for $0<y<x<1$ and $a \in (0,1)$.

I already tried some stuff, through logarithms, concave functions and binomial theorem but without much success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: $x^a-y^a=(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^ax^{a-k}y^k$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508731/proving-that-x-frac1n-is-uniformly-continuous-over-0-infty-with-t/2508788#2508788 A somewhat simpler method is to prove $x^a$ is $a$-Hölderian, since you can deduce uniform continuity from this property.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern $a\in (0,1)$

Comment: @zwim i guess that will work for what i want. Thx

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is simply wrong: you can rewrite it as

$$x^a-x<y^a-y$$
which would mean that you want the function $x\mapsto x^a-x$ to be decreasing over $(0,1)$, except it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong.

Try $a=\frac{1}{2}$, $x=\frac{1}{4}$ and $y=\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: yeah, thx. My mistake.

Comment: You are welcome!