# Show that $\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{a}<\sqrt[n]{b-a}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 \leq a<b$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2$

a) Show that $\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{a}<\sqrt[n]{b-a}$.

b) Show that $\frac{a-1}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{a}-1$

I tried Induction and Mean value theorem, but Failed.

Comment: Check my answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2508788/399263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one : you have $\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{a}=\sqrt[n]{a}(\sqrt[n]{b/a}-1)$ and $\sqrt[n]{a-b}=\sqrt[n]{a}\sqrt[n]{b/a-1}$ so you can divide by $\sqrt[n]{a}$ on both side (if $a \ne 0$, otherwise it is trivial).

You should now compare $f(x)= \sqrt[n]{x}-1$ and $g(x)=\sqrt[n]{x-1}$ for $x \geq 1$. Since $f(1)=g(1)=0$ and $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ for $x \geq 1$ you have your answer.

For the second part see the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note as written it is false, since letting $a=0$ yields $\sqrt[n]{b} < \sqrt[n]{b}$, so you need $\le$, not $<$.

The second one you can write as $a - na^{1/n} \ge 1 - n$ so defined $f(x) = x-nx^{1/n}$ and find its minimum.

In a similar way, you can define $f(a,b) = (b-a)^{1/n} - b^{1/n} + a^{1/n}$ and minimize that over $0 \le a < b \in \mathbb{R}$ to prove that $f(a,b) \ge 0$.

Comment: For the second part, it is easier to just apply $AM \ge GM$ on $a,1,1,1,1,1...(n-1 times)$ and subtract both sides by 1.

Comment: @Forester +1, let the OP choose whatever suits him best